# Problem with install libgconf-2-4

Tags: system

I'm trying to install libgconf-2-4 and get the below error

```
Setting up gconf2-common (3.2.6-3ubuntu6) ...
dpkg: error processing package gconf2-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgconf-2-4:amd64:
 libgconf-2-4:amd64 depends on gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package gconf2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgconf-2-4:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf-service-backend:
 gconf-service-backend depends on libgconf-2-4 (= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.
 gconf-service-backend depends on gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package gconf2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf-service-backend (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf-service:
 gconf-service depends on gconf-service-backend (= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package gconf-service-backend is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf-service (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on gconf-service; however:
  Package gconf-service is not configured yet.
 gconf2 depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.
 gconf2 depends on gconf-service-backend (= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package gconf-service-backend is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of insomnia:
 insomnia depends on gconf2; however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.
 insomnia depends on gconf-service; however:
  Package gconf-service is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package insomnia (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2-common
 libgconf-2-4:amd64
 gconf-service-backend
 gconf-service
 gconf2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command

`sudo apt-get install gconf2-common libgconf-2-4`